# How to display submenu to page in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm using Orchard Cms 1.9 version. I want to add submenu to content pages?

This is example:

[image: Example]

Displaying Current Page:

[image: Current page]

Comment: try something and post here

Comment: You already did. It's just that the theme you're using doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: I want to integrate the sub-menu to a content page. Is there a link where we can sample about it? So, it x1 x pages of the sub-menu that displays the content side of x2 and x3 to add the submenu. I'm sorry for my english :)

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to achieve. The menu looks fine and it also looks it renders ok. Correct me if I'm wrong, but do you want to display a **secondary** menu, specific for each page (like a sidebar menu?)? Something like the admin, where you have a menu on the left and sometimes additional tabs on a page?